# Generating doc file from html

Tags: java, css, grails, doc

I am working on project which converts `html` to a `.doc` file.  I have implemented the html using `div`s not `td`/`table`. When I generate/download the doc file, the css which I have used in html is not applied.

I did some research and I found that .doc does not support some css attributes e.g position, float etc.

https://superuser.com/questions/146453/css-absolute-position-dont-work-in-ms-word

Is there any alternative to get css applied in `.doc` format

Can someone please help

Comment: then Why dont you use table. Because It common for both html as well as in msword.

Comment: I am at the stage where i cant changed my implementation since project is vast, so please suggest me if there is possible alternate/solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is list of supported attribute.
[Ms word supported html tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28office.12%29.aspx)

Here you can see and use it carefully in your project. It will help to make you minor change.
Maximum tag has full support except div tag.
[Link for check COREEXTENDED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28office.12%29.aspx#Word2007MailHTMLandCSS_CoreExtended)

div has COREEXTENDED support. You can see it at link.